# Run gunicorn like service

Tags: gunicorn, systemd

I want configure gunicorn in a service.

I have this configuration for the service :

```
[Unit]
Description=test

[Service]
WorkingDirectory=/var/www/cmdb
Type=forking
Restart=always
ExecStart=/var/www/test/bin/gunicorn --workers=4 --bind=0.0.0.0:8080 test.wsgi:application

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

My problem is that it doesn't run. I have this error when I start the service :

```
gunicorn.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=203/EXEC
gunicorn.service: Unit entered failed state.
gunicorn.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
gunicorn.service: Start request repeated too quickly.
```

I don't find the mistakes in my configuration. Does someone have an idea ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that you're running in a virtualenv, the gunicorn bin should be something like this:

```
/var/www/cmdb/venv/bin/gunicorn
```

Instead of

```
/var/www/test/bin/gunicorn
```

Anyway, I use something like this in my system and it work fine:

```
[Unit]
Description = SampleApp
After = network.target

[Service]
PIDFile = /run/cmdb/cmdb.pid
WorkingDirectory = /var/www/cmdb
ExecStartPre = /bin/mkdir /run/cmdb
ExecStart = /var/www/cmdb/venv/bin/gunicorn test.wsgi:application -b 0.0.0.0:8000 --pid /run/cmdb/cmdb.pid
ExecReload = /bin/kill -s HUP $MAINPID
ExecStop = /bin/kill -s TERM $MAINPID
ExecStopPost = /bin/rm -rf /run/cmdb

[Install]
WantedBy = multi-user.target
```

Note: this example use the root as the app user. I do recommend use an user to your app, with restricted permissions.